# How should a question be modified to meet the quality standards?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, error-message

While posting a question in one of the SE sites, I encountered the following error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> ```
> It does not meet our quality standards.
> ```

I think this message is not clear enough. It doesn't state how I should modify my question to make it eligible to be posted. I don't know whether I should add more tags, or should I add more characters to the title or body of the question, or what?

Comment: What were you trying to post? This normally means what it says; all code / links etc...

Comment: I finally managed to get my question posted. The title was only three words and I made it longer. (in islam.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quality filter looks for characteristics in your post text that have a high correlation with low-quality questions.  If you're running into the quality filter, chances are good that you're simply asking a poor-quality question.

What constitutes a good quality question?

1. It contains sufficient detail so that it is answerable.
2. It is clear and understandable.
3. It observes proper grammar, capitalization and punctuation.

We don't provide additional details about the quality filter, because people who are lazy and don't want to put effort into improving their question will use these details to override the quality filter.

Comment: Taking those details in order to sneak in lazy posts would be a sort of admirably efficient lazy.